# ActiveRecord: query records and get specific item first, sort rest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What is want to do is exactly this:
[mysql SQL: specific item to be first and then to sort the rest of the items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417980/mysql-sql-specific-item-to-be-first-and-then-to-sort-the-rest-of-the-items)
but for ActiveRecord.

Going by the solution for mySql provided in above question, i tried:

```
.order('user_id = 9 DESC')
```

but it didn't worked. Please help

Comment: what did it do instead? what does the generated query look like?

Comment: did you try any of the other answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5418087/3334690)... notably Amadan's or Dumitrescu Bogdan's?

Comment: @user3334690 i am extremely sorry. It does exactly what it should have done. Thanks for your help. If you want to write a detailed answer please do, I'll close this question. Thanks

Comment: it happens to all of us... you could just delete the question if you want