# Order by score then by time

Tags: php, sql

My table structure is below:

```
Name   email          score time
Hello  abc@gmail.com  100   15
Hello  abc@gmail.com  58    10
Test   def@gmail.com  100   12 
Stack  xyz@gmail.com  90    20
Test   def@gmail.com  50    40
```

Using select query

```
$q="SELECT name, MAX(score) as score ,email FROM users GROUP BY email ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Below result generates.

```
Name   email          score time
Hello  abc@gmail.com  100   15
Test   def@gmail.com  100   12 
Stack  xyz@gmail.com  90    20
```

What I am confused is, if two user have same score, I want to sort the result based on lowest time, since "Test" user scored 100 in 12 seconds, it should come first.

Comment: may this help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/php-mysql-order-by-two-columns

Comment: Recommended : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417980/mysql-sql-specific-item-to-be-first-and-then-to-sort-the-rest-of-the-items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name, MAX(score) as score, email 
FROM users GROUP BY email 
ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC, time ASC LIMIT 10; # note how multiple column ordering is made
```

Read more: [SQL multiple column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Comment: Thanks dear. Working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this mysql query

```
  $q="SELECT name, MAX(score) as score 
       ,email FROM users GROUP BY email 
      ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC,time LIMIT 10 ";
```