# To sort by rather than filter by

Tags: php, mysql, filter

My existing query below work perfect. However, I have a new field that determines the area order in which these results are displayed.

Example, if user is browsing website one (ID 123) then all records 
for area 123 and 234 and 543 must be displayed, but records for area ID 123 first, then records for 234 and 543 in according to my existing order. The variable which area this is will always be `$AreaID`.

Please remember I am not filtering records out by that area, I simply want to put the records for that area above the other all in `cont_id` ASC Order

I cannot find an example anywhere to even give me a direction in which I can experiment. I would imagine i have to select them separately in some way?

```
$sql = "select * 
    from 202_articles 
    where cont_date_published <= CURDATE() 
    and cont_time_published < CURTIME() 
    and cont_category_id = $TypeID 
    ORDER by cont_id ASC 
    LIMIT 25";
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at `group by`?

Comment: Seriously consider storing date and time as a single entity. And, once you've seriously considered that, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql SQL: specific item to be first and then to sort the rest of the items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417980/mysql-sql-specific-item-to-be-first-and-then-to-sort-the-rest-of-the-items)

Comment: Thank you Hamza, that helped

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a column named `AreaID`, then use a case to sort by that condition first:

```
$sql = "select * 
from 202_articles 
where cont_date_published <= CURDATE() 
and cont_time_published < CURTIME() 
and cont_category_id = $TypeID 
ORDER by
CASE WHEN AreaID = $AreaID THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
AreaID,
cont_id ASC 
LIMIT 25";
```

Comment: Thank you ! a mixture of your suggestion and the link of the duplication above did the trick! - I did not know there can be conditions in a QUERY. Something new!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select * 
from 202_articles 
where cont_date_published <= CURDATE() 
and cont_time_published < CURTIME() 
and cont_category_id = $TypeID 
ORDER by cont_id ASC 
LIMIT 25";
```

if you know the area then you can use following query instead of above.

```
$sql = "select * 
from 202_articles 
where cont_date_published <= CURDATE() 
and cont_time_published < CURTIME() 
and cont_category_id = $TypeID 
ORDER by cont_id='$userarea' ASC, cont_id ASC 
LIMIT 25";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple `UNION JOIN` to select everything with a specific `cont_id`, then select everything else ordering by `cont_id ASC`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    202_articles
WHERE
    cont_date_published <= CURDATE()
AND cont_time_published < CURTIME()
AND cont_category_id = $TypeID
AND cont_id = $AreaID
UNION
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        202_articles
    WHERE
        cont_date_published <= CURDATE()
    AND cont_time_published < CURTIME()
    AND cont_category_id = $TypeID
    ORDER BY
        cont_id ASC
    LIMIT 25
```

POC: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ae07/1