# How to do Laravel Eloquent get with a specific item appearing first for pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a use case where I need to get all the rows from a table with the currently selected row appearing first and show the rest as the user scrolls through the table. I currently have it setup where I use the eloquent find to fetch the individual  item and then use the eloquent get and merge the results if the page number is 1. Is there a better way to handle this or is this the best way to handle this use case?

Comment: Usually you'd use `orderBy` but really it depends on what your code is actually doing

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I'll try and add my code once i am in front of a computer, but I am trying to fetch all the images uploaded by the user in a lightbox and want to show the one that's currently selected by the user first and then show the rest of the images as he tries to scroll in the media manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL's order by, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5418044/510788):

```
$selectedImageId = 2;
$images = \App\Models\Image::orderByRaw('case when id=? then -1 else 0 end, created_at desc', [$selectedImageId])->get();
```

Comment: It would be more flexible if you did `case when id=? then -1 else 0 end` in the cases where you would want to ensure the specific id is first but then order by something else.

Comment: Am I missing something? Why would you need a `CASE` here? The accepted answer in the thread you linked to uses a simple `ORDER BY`

Comment: It is more explicit. When doing something like this, what is not used daily by most developers, I prefer to do it the verbose way, so I don't need to comment what it does. It's just my personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
$result = Model::orderByRaw("id = $selected DESC")->get();
```