# Specific item to be first and then to sort the rest of the items in Laravel6

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to sort my data just like:[specific item to be first and then to sort the rest of the items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417980/mysql-sql-specific-item-to-be-first-and-then-to-sort-the-rest-of-the-items) in laravel.

So in my case,

colors table:

```
id    A        B  
1   cyan    deep green
2   green   dark red
3   yellow  pink
4   red     light green
5   blue    black
```

ColorController.php

```
$keyword = $request->input('keyword');
$query = Color::query(); 

if(!empty($keyword)){
$query->where('A','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
->orWhere('B','like','%'.$keyword.'%');

$data = $query->orderBy('A', 'ASC')->paginate(4);
```

then in the search bar, if I type "green",
my website shows:

```
cyan(deep green)
green(dark red)
red(light green)
```

But, I want to sort A column matched item first, like:

```
green(dark red)
cyan(deep green)
red(light green)
```

So I rewrote controller like:

```
$data = $query->orderByRaw("IF('A' = $keyword) DESC")->paginate(4);
```

But, it just gets error.

[*additional info*]

I also tried

```
$data = $query->orderByRaw("('A' = '%$keyword%') DESC , B asc")->paginate(4);
```

It doesn't produce error but $keyword is produced as strings, not variable.
If I take the ' ' out of $keyword, it produces error
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'green' in 'order clause'".

So how can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your `orderBy` query:

```
$data = $query->orderByRaw("(A like '%$keyword%') DESC")->paginate(4);
```

try `'A'` if the above produces a column error.

Comment: I tried your way, but didn't sort as I desired. Then I tried `$data = $query->orderByRaw("('A' = '%$keyword%') DESC , B asc")->paginate(4);` then it just worked $keyword as string, not variable. So I changed `'%$keyword%'` to `%$keyword%` then it produces error. So the problem is that I can't call $keyword as variable.

Comment: I changed again `$data = $query->orderByRaw("A = '$keyword' DESC, B ASC")->paginate(4);` then now properly it worked! Your suggestion helped me alot!