# JPA Specification sort by specific value first

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using JPA Specification to retrieve data for my Spring boot app.

I have a mySQL query as below to get the list that I wanted:

```
select *
from TableA
order by colB = 'C' DESC, colB;
```

Result: -

```
no    | colB
3     |  C
1     |  A
2     |  B
4     |  D
```

My question is, is it possible to convert into JPA Specification? I have already looked around but could not find what I wanted.

```
     Page<Object> page = tableARepository.findAll(
            (Specification<Object>) (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {

                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

                if (sortConfig.getSpecification() != null) {
                    Predicate predicate = sortConfig.getSpecification().toPredicate(root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder);
                    predicates.add(predicate);
                }
                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
            },
            sortConfig.getPageable()
    );
```

Comment: order by colB = 'C' is not valid. Do you want to do where colB = 'C' or what else?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it is a legit query. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417980/mysql-sql-specific-item-to-be-first-and-then-to-sort-the-rest-of-the-items

Comment: But it's not a valid SQL statement in terms of standard. So you cannot transform it into JPA query

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I think I didn't state clearly, I was using mySQL query.

Comment: I know. And I say you can't turn your query in JPA Criteria because it's not SQL standard

Comment: @SimonMartinelli okay noted... thanks

Comment: To convert it to a standard query, `ORDER BY CASE ...` is most likely what you want

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent in JPA for this query, since it is vendor specific. What you can do, like crizzis said, is create an ORDER BY CASE clause. For example:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE
    -- First condition with higher priority
    WHEN priority = 1 AND situation_id = 2 THEN 1

    -- Second condition with less priority
    WHEN situation_id = 1 THEN 2

    -- Third condition
    WHEN priority = 0 AND situation_id = 2 THEN 3

    -- Fourth condition
    WHEN situation_id = 3 THEN 4
END, 
-- Second ordering column
creation_date DESC
```

And then create a JPQL query with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested, but you may try something like below!

```
tableARepo.findAllByColBByOrderByColBDesc(col_b_type col_b_parameter)
```

or maybe

```
tableARepo.findAllByColBByOrderByColBDesc(String colB)
```

Comment: I tried for you, it's not working